# Real analysis Folland problem 8.18

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

> Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.
>   **a.** The $L^2$ derivative $f'$ (in the sense of Exercises 8 and 9) exists iff $\xi \widehat f\in L^2$, in which case $\widehat{f'}(\xi)=2\pi i\xi \widehat{f}(\xi)$.
>   **b.** If the $L^2$ derivative $f'$ exists then
>   $$\left[\int|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right]^2 \le 4 \int x|f(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \int |f'(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
>   (If the integrals on the right are finite then one can integrate by parts to obtain $\int|f|^2=-2\operatorname{Re}x\overline ff'$.)
>   **c. (Heisenberg inequality)** For any $b,\beta\in\mathbb R$,
>   $$\int (x-b)^2 |f(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \int (\xi-\beta)^2 |\widehat f(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi \ge \frac{\|f\|^4_2}{16\pi^2}.$$

The definition of $L^{p}$ derivative:

Suppose that $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$.If there exists $h\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ such that 
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\Vert \frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}-h(x)\Vert_{p}=0,$$
we call $h$ the **(strong)**$L^{p}$ **derivative** of $f$.

Actually I get stuck at the beginning of the question, since I just have no idea with how to use the condition of the $L^2$ derivative. I tried to find some useful theorems that might be useful on Folland's book(like The Plancherel Theorem), but they all need the condition that f $f\in L^1$.

(I have added the definition of $L^{p}$ derivative.)

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you post the text of the exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have uploaded an image of the exercise.

Comment: The text you posted refers to other exercises to complete the definition.

Comment: Again, you are more likely to get help if you post the text, rather than a link, or  even a picture of it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started, I have retyped some text from your picture.

Comment: @JiamingXu I've written an explanation in order to explain how to get the underlined result, being unaware that the question is now put on hold by moderators. If you manage to get unlocked your question by editing, I'll be happy to post the already written answer.

Comment: @Bob I have added the definition, but I don't know how I can get the question unlocked or whether there is some other contents that I have to add.

Comment: @JiamingXu you have to show that you attemped to solve the exercise, illustrate what ideas you developed in the process and where you got stuck

Comment: Part A is solved here. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474561/a-function-is-l2-differentiable-if-and-only-if-xi-widehatf-xi-in-l2

Part B and C are solved on page 158 of 

https://books.google.com/books?id=FAOc24bTfGkC&q=%22The+mathematical+thrust+of+the+principle%22&pg=PA158#v=snippet&q=%22The%20mathematical%20thrust%20of%20the%20principle%22&f=false

Comment: I also believe that in this problems current state it does not deserve to be locked and had it not been locked, I would have answered it. I have given sources instead in the comment above.