# Bound on complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I was reading the following question, [A function is $L^2$-differentiable if and only if $\xi\widehat{f}(\xi) \in L^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474561/a-function-is-l2-differentiable-if-and-only-if-xi-widehatf-xi-in-l2), and in the accepted answer there is a bound
$$\left\lvert\frac{e^{2\pi ih\xi}-1}{h} \right\rvert \leqslant 2\pi \lvert \xi\rvert$$
and although it may not be complicated i got stuck on showing this bound, i do see that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \left\lvert\frac{e^{2\pi ih\xi}-1}{h} \right\rvert = 2\pi \lvert \xi\rvert$$

So i thought of showing this function is an increasing function but all i got was a mess on calculations, is there an easier way to see that bound?

Edit: i dont know what my idea was but definetely increasing function is not a way to show the bound

Comment: don't forget that $|e^{ir}| = 1$ for real $r$, so your LHS is bounded above by $2/h$. And as $h \to 0$ we have that $e^{2\pi i h \xi} \to 1$ so that might help.

Comment: @PrimeMover i just need the upper bound in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem, but it must be in the whole domain, my goal with the limit is to show where i think the bound appears

Comment: Maybe mean value theorem with  a=h and b=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^{2\pi i\xi}-1|=2\pi |\xi||\int_0^{h} e^{2\pi i t\xi} dt|\leq 2\pi |\xi||\int_0^{h} 1 dt| \leq 2\pi |\xi|$ if $|h| \leq 1$.

Comment: I do need a bound for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$, i could do it now with mean value theorem

Comment: Actually i couldn't, still trying

Comment: But i see i only need to look at small $h$ in the original question, thus i'm accepting the answer