# Looking for a source: Fourier inversion of $f \in L^1$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is there a book where I can find a thorough proof of the following assertion?

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be continuous at zero and $\hat{f}\ge0$. Then $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and
>   $$f(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i\, t\xi} \,d\xi$$
>   almost everywhere.

I'm looking for the context in which this Lemma is stated, more than the actual proof.

---

I've finally found the source:
E. M. Stein, G. Weiss, *Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces*, Princeton University Press, 1971. **$\S$1. Corollary 1.26 (p.15)**

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: We know this [fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187326/how-to-prove-a-function-is-the-fourier-transform-of-another-l1-function/187494#187494).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal On [this lecture notes](http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2007/harm-analysis/FT1.pdf), p3. Satz 10. But they are in German.

Answer (score 2):

By OP:

I've finally found the source: E. M. Stein, G. Weiss, Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces, Princeton University Press, 1971. §1. Corollary 1.26 (p.15)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the proof please see here: [Proof of Fourier Inverse formula for $L^1$ case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465565/proof-of-fourier-inverse-formula-for-l1-case)

Further to another German reference that rather pays attention to context than proof is here http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/hs2007/harm-analysis/FT2.pdf

Comment: The linked answer doesn't treat the interesting part, that if $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $\widehat{f} \geqslant 0$, then $\widehat{f} \in L^1$.