# Fourier Transform and its Inverse

Tags: fourier-analysis

Could anyone show me how to prove the following results about Fourier Transform, please? It is stated in my book without proof. Thank you.

Let $\mathcal F$ denote the Fourier linear operator and $f$ be a $\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$ function. Then $$\mathcal F^2 (f) = f (-x).$$ That is, if we apply the Fourier transform twice, we get a spatially reversed version of the function.

Comment: Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465565/proof-of-fourier-inverse-formula-for-l1-case . Also note that either you will have to interpret the "second" Fourier transform in the sense of distributions, or you will have to assume $\mathcal{F}f \in L^1$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the following (unitary) definition of the Fourier transform

$$\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=F(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx\\
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}d\xi$$

you have

$$\mathcal{F}^2\{f(x)\}=\mathcal{F}\{F(\xi)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\xi)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}d\xi=f(-x)$$

Comment: I don't see where you got the equation $f(x)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} F( \xi ) e^{2 \pi i x \xi}\,d\xi$.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan: That's just the definition of the inverse Fourier transform.