# Inverse Fourier transform of a Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am currently trying to piece together a proof of the Fourier inversion theorem which is appropriate for a probability theory context. The approach I am taking is [smushing with a gaussian kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4437742/445105)
$$
g_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\epsilon^2}\right)
$$

and then using the fact
$$
h * g_\epsilon \to h \quad \text{in } L^1
$$

from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/466038/445105). Unfortunately this requires that $h$ is in $L^1$ so to have a complete proof, I need that

$$
\hat{\varphi}_f: x\mapsto \int e^{-itx} \underbrace{\int e^{ity} f(y)dy}_{=\varphi_f(t)}dt \quad \in L^1 
$$

for all $f\in L^1$. Because then I have $f*g_\epsilon \to f$ **and** $\hat{\varphi}_f * g_\epsilon \to \hat{\varphi}_f$. So I get $2\pi f=\hat{\varphi}_f$ by uniqueness of limits.

I can not think of a proof though. Obviously I can not use Fourier inversion already.

---

##### EDIT: Simpler Equivalent Question

If I have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int e^{-\tfrac12 t^2 \epsilon^2} e^{itx}\hat{f}(t)dt = f(x)
$$

does that imply that

$$
\int e^{itx} \hat{f}(t)dt =f(x)
$$

In other words can I swap limits and integration, if I know that the limits of integrals converges (in this case)?

Comment: You said that $f\in L^1$. The question is what is $g_\epsilon$. If $g\in L^1,\int g = 1$ and $g_\epsilon(t) = g(t/ \epsilon) / \epsilon$ then $f\ast g_\epsilon \to f$ in $L^1$. The simplest choice of $g$ is $\frac1\pi\frac{\sin(t)^2}{t^2}$  because $g(t)=\frac2\pi \int_{-2}^2 (1-|y/2|) e^{iyt} dy$ so that $f \ast g_\epsilon = ...$

Comment: @reuns ah sorry, a gaussian kernel (clarified in the question)

Comment: You misunderstood the point. Without using any theorem, if $g_\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G_\epsilon(y) e^{iyt}dy$ and $\hat{f}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-iyt}dt$ (and $f,G_\epsilon$ are $L^1$) then

$f \ast g_\epsilon (t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(t) G_\epsilon(y) e^{iyt}dy$ which is a regularized version of the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{f}$. With a right choice of $g_\epsilon$ this regularized version converges to $f$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ (in $L^1$), so we have a regularized version of the Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: @reuns but I want to remove that regularization again to get the unregularized version of the inverse fourier transform theorem. Does that make sense? Or have I misunderstood what you are trying to say?

Comment: You need some assumptions such as $\hat{f} \in L^1$ to look at the unregularized version.

Comment: I don't want $\hat{f}\in L^1$, I want $\hat{\hat{f}}\in L^1$ for $f\in L^1$, or $\check{\hat{f}}$ to be more precise

Comment: The regularized version of $\hat{\hat{f}}$ is equal to $f$ (that's the regularized Fourier inversion theorem, that I'm saying is the main point here). We don't have any definition of $\hat{\hat{f}}$ if $\hat{f}$ is not in $L^1$.

Comment: @reuns Okay let's put in another way: I am assuming that $f$ is a density, and therefore $\varphi_f$ the characteristic function. The characteristic function always exists. And if I started out with a density, the fourier transform of the characteristic function should be the density again right? Are there really some corner-cases where that blows up in our face?

Comment: When $\varphi_f$ is not $L^1$, you don't know how to define its Fourier transform. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi_f(y)e^{iyt}dy$ doesn't have to converge. That's why you regularize it as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi_f(y) G_\epsilon(y)e^{iyt}dy$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$. With the right choice of $G_\epsilon$ this converges to $f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135891/discussion-between-felix-b-and-reuns).

Comment: @reuns Thinking about your comments I phrased and (I think) equivalent question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to write $e^{-t^2\epsilon^2/2}$ as the Fourier transform of a Guassian? If so, then you could write your integral as the convolution of a Guassian and $f$, and then you could take the limit.