# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \min (f(x),f(x+1/n)) \, d\lambda (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, d\lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ measurable and can be Lebesgue integrated. Is it true that
>
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \min (f(x),f(x+1/n)) \, d\lambda (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, d\lambda \quad ?$$

I did not find a counterexample nor a proof for this. Could you help me?

**EDIT:** with @KaviRamaMurthy 's comment:

\begin{align*}
0
&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, d\lambda - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \min (f(x),f(x+1/n)) \, d\lambda (x) \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f -\min (f(x),f(x+1/n)) \, d\lambda (x) \\
&\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f -\min (f(x),f(x+1/n)) \rvert \, d\lambda (x) \\
&\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f - f(x+1/n) \rvert \, d\lambda (x)  \\
&\to 0
\end{align*}

Is my proof correct? Or did I make some mistakes?

Comment: Consider RHS $-$ LHS. Use the well known fact that $\int |f(x)-f(x+\frac 1 n)| d\lambda \to 0$.

Comment: Do you have any other conditions on $f$? Currently, it might be possible that the limit $f(x + 1/n)$ does not exist. And due to the DCT you can certainly take the limit inside, so then we would find that this limit in general need not exists.

Comment: Point-wise convergence is a *hypothesis* of DCT. If the limit does not exist, it cannot apply

Comment: Of course, my bad.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will write

$$ T_n f(x) = f(x+\tfrac{1}{n}) $$

for simplicity. Then by noting that $| (a \wedge b) - a | \leq |b - a|$, we get

$$ \| f \wedge (T_n f) - f \|_{L^1} \leq \| T_n f - f \|_{L^1}. $$

Now the $L^1$-continuity of the translation tells that $T_n f \to f$ in $L^1$, and so, $f \wedge (T_n f) \to f$ in $L^1$ as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $\int |f(x) - f(x+1/n) |  d x \to 0$?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF., It is typically proved by invoking the density argument. More precisely, the claim may first be established for functions in a nice, dense subspace of $L^1$ (such as compactly supported continuous functions) and then can be extended to all of $L^1$ by density. (For example, you may check [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458230/continuity-of-l1-functions-with-respect-to-translation).)

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, but in this case does ∧ mean min?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach without using the $L^{1}$ translation  fact, maybe somehow more complicated, but it depends:

By a step function $\varphi$ we mean that $\varphi$ is a finite linear combination of the characteristic functions of intervals.

Now by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem one has $\int\min(\varphi(x),\varphi(x+1/n))dx\rightarrow\int\varphi$ for any step function $\varphi$.

Use the well-known fact that step functions are $L^{1}$ dense, we pick a sequence $(\varphi_{N})$ of step functions such that $\varphi_{N}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. and $\int|\varphi_{N}(x)-\varphi_{N-1}(x)|dx<2^{-N}$ for all $N=1,2,...$

By the inequality that $|\min(a,b)-a|\leq|b-a|$, we can further assume that $f,\varphi_{N}\geq 0$. The result will follow by triangle inequality once we consider $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$.

Now we see that
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\min(f(x),f(x+1/n))dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\int\bigg(\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))-\min(f(x),\varphi_{N-1}(x+1/n))\bigg)dx,
\end{align*}
where we have used Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem in the second equality by the observation that $0\leq\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))\leq f(x)$, and in the last equality we set $\varphi_{0}=0$.

Recall the inequality that $|\min(a,b)-\min(a,c)|\leq|b-c|$, one has
\begin{align*}
&\left|\int\bigg(\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))-\min(f(x),\varphi_{N-1}(x+1/n))\bigg)dx\right|\\
&\leq\int|\varphi_{N}(x+1/n)-\varphi_{N-1}(x+1/n)|dx\\
&=\int|\varphi_{N}(x)-\varphi_{N-1}(x)|dx\\
&<\dfrac{1}{2^{N}}.
\end{align*}
Since $\sum_{N}2^{-N}<\infty$, once again by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\int\bigg(\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))-\min(f(x),\varphi_{N-1}(x+1/n))\bigg)dx\\
&=\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\bigg(\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x+1/n))-\min(f(x),\varphi_{N-1}(x+1/n))\bigg)dx\\
&=\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\int\bigg(\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x))-\min(f(x),\varphi_{N-1}(x))\bigg)dx\\
&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x))dx\\
&=\int\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\min(f(x),\varphi_{N}(x))dx\\
&=\int f(x)dx.
\end{align*}