# integrable function having zero integrable of difference

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \int \vert f(x+h)-f(x) \vert dx=0.$$

My question is I know since $f$ is integral can I use that for any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find a finite interval such that on the complement of this the ball we have

$$\int_{B^c} \vert f \vert dx < \epsilon.$$

Can I use this to prove my statement? And use some relationship between $\vert f(x+h)-f(x) \vert$ and $\vert f(x) \vert$? Just need hint. sorry if this has been asked I couldn't find it.

Comment: This result is proved in Rudin's RCA. It requires approximation of $f$ by continuous functions with compact support.

Comment: See [Continuity of Translation in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458234/568204).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks!