# Properties of the functions $f(x-t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for some $1 \leq p < \infty$. Given $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we set $f_t(x) := f(x-t)$.

Here I'm not sure if we can view $\{f_t\}$ as a sequence of functions, since they are not enumerated in a discrete sense. Is it true that when $t \rightarrow 0$, we have $f_t \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. and $||f_t||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$?

I'm also not sure if it's possible to apply results such as Dominated convergence theorem and Fatou's lemma when the functions are indexed like this, even if we were to set $g_t(x) := f(x-1/t)$ and let $t$ tend to infinity.

Comment: A.s. convergence is not true but convergence of $L^{p}$ norms is true and it is proved in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So I suppose that whenever a result states that "Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions...", they automatically exclude functions of the above scenario?

Comment: What is $t$ approaching in your limit? Moreover, $||f_t||_p = ||f||_p $ so the $L^p$ limit is true.

Comment: @DionelJaime it approaches 0, I left it out by mistake, edited

Comment: Then pointwise is not true. It's true if $f$ is continuous at $x$. But there are $L^p$ functions which are discontinuous a.e.

Comment: $t\to 0$ is really a sequence not a net but the notation is hiding that implication slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can easily extend the basic theorems MCT, Fatou, DCT to this situation. For example, $f_t\to f$ in $L^p$ as $t\to 0$ means that the function $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(t):=\|f_t-f\|_p$ is such that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\phi(t)=0$. For such real functions, checking something about limits is the same as checking along every sequence. Meaning that
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\phi(t)&=0
\end{align}
if and only if for every sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}t_n=0$, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(t_n)&=0.
\end{align}
So, this allows you to reduce to the case of sequences and thus use your usual sequential variant of DCT/MCT/Fatou.

Comment: I know that we have $||f_t||_p = ||f||_p$ since $L^p$-norms are translation invariant after a bit of recalling, but how does this show that $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} ||f_t - f||_p = 0$?

Comment: @KelvinLian my answer here addresses your second query regarding applicability of DCT/Fatou to non-sequences. Your first part is called continuity of translation in $L^p$, and has been discussed several times on this site. The idea is to first prove it for $f\in C_c(\Bbb{R})$, and then use density to prove for all $f\in L^p(\Bbb{R})$. See [Continuity of $L^1$ functions with respect to translation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458234/568204) for the details. There, the proof is given for $L^1$, but $L^p$ is very similar.

Comment: Pointwise a.e convergence is not true btw (as you've already been told in the comments above). All we can deduce is there is a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $t_n\to 0$ and $f_{t_n}\to f$ pointwise a.e as $n\to\infty$. This is just a general measure theory fact. Convergence in $L^p$ implies some subsequence converges pointwise a.e.