# Prove that $ \lim _{a \rightarrow 0}\left\|T_{a} f-f\right\|_{L^{1}}=0 . $

Tags: continuity, lp-spaces

Let $T_a(f):=f(x-a)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Let also $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and uniformly continuous. I would like to prove that:
$$
\lim _{a \rightarrow 0}\left\|T_{a} f-f\right\|_{L^{1}}=0 .
$$
This is my attempt:

Let us first assume that $f$ is continuous and has compact support in the bounded interval $[c, d]$. For $y \in]-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}[$ the function
$$
\phi(x)=f(x-y)-f(x)
$$
has support in the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{2}+c, d+\frac{1}{2}\right]$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can for any given $\epsilon>0$ find $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|f(x-y)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon \text { for all } x \in \mathbb{R} \text { whenever }|y| \leq \delta
$$
with the choice of $\delta=d-c+1$ we thus obtain that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\|\phi(x)\right\|_1 &=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}+c}^{\frac{1}{2}+d}|f(x-y)-f(x)| d x \\
& \leq \epsilon \sqrt{d-c+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
I stop here. How I can deal with the case of an arbitrary function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of $L^1$ functions with respect to translation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458230/continuity-of-l1-functions-with-respect-to-translation)

Comment: @OliverDiaz thank you, but I do not understand the accepted answer provided in your link. E.g., if we look at $g$, why it should be uniformly continous?